# How to Start thread only on demand in perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl

In c#, we can create thread and start thread only on need like following (if I am correct)

```
Thread th=new thread("function");
th.start()
```

But in perl, when I create itself it has started. For example

```
$thread1=thread->create("function");
```

But I want to create 4 thread. I should start only on need. And I've to check whether it's running or not? if thread is not running, then I've to start the same thread by passing different parameter. How to do that in perl ?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html

Comment: How to do that without queue ?

Comment: If you want to reuse existing threads, there should be some kind of communication between workers and main thread, and queue does that.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I don't find any simple example for this. Would you post your answer for this with simple 3 thread using thread::queue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple jobs can be sent into the queue, and they are waiting for their turn to be passed to the worker.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $no_of_workers = 4;
my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
# Worker thread
my @thr = map {

  my $t = threads->create(sub{

    # Thread will loop until no more work
    while (defined(my $item = $q->dequeue())) {
        # Do work on $item
        print "$item\n";
    }
  });

  {queue => $q, thread => $t, id => $_};

} 1 .. $no_of_workers;


# Send work to each thread
$_->{queue}->enqueue("Job for thread $_->{id}") for @thr;

for (@thr) {
  # Signal that there is no more work to be sent
  # $_->{queue}->end();

  # similar to $queue->end() for older perl
  $_->{queue}->enqueue(undef) for @thr;

  # wait for threads to finish
  $_->{thread}->join();
}
```

Assigning jobs `0..19` in circular way to workers,

```
for my $i (0 .. 19) {
  my $t = $thr[$i % @thr]; # $i % @thr => 0,1,2,3, 0,1,2,3, ..
  $t->{queue}->enqueue("Job for thread $t->{id}");
}
```

Comment: Where I can send subroutine as work ? In which line, I can add ?

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. I am new to perl

Comment: replace `print "$item\n";` with `your_function($item)`

Comment: Thank you. How to assign again 4 job for this 4 threads after finish its job?

Comment: In this I can understand that, 4 threads doing separate 4 tasks. After finish their task, I want to assign again 4 tasks for them. How to do that ? Actually, I have 20 tasks. I want to do that 20 tasks for 5 times with 4 threads. Did I communicate correctly ?

Comment: Really Thank you so much :-). I want you to confirm one thing. Do you mean $thr[0] for 1st thread and $thr[1] for 2nd thread ?

Comment: @Vijay yes; array index in perl are starting with `0`

Comment: It affects cpu usage. Because of that my system hangs. Why is that ?

Comment: How to pass more than two value using "$t->{queue}->enqueue("Job for thread $t->{id}");" and get those values using "while (my $item = $q->dequeue())" and pass those values to subroutine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45890/discussion-between-vijay-and-mpapec)

Comment: Hi i got the following error, while using your code. please, Help me to come out from the following error. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312493/got-error-while-using-thread-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment32122354_21312493

Comment: I don't know what is the problem here. For my it works fine. I've created the queue outside the function .. works fine. I don't know what is the issue in that ..

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a queue for each thread! You'll end up with idle threads even if work's available.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;

use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 4;

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   print("Job: $job\n");
   sleep(rand(4));  # Pretending to do $job
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         while (defined(my $item = $q->dequeue())) {
            worker($item);
         }
      };
   }

   # Give the workers work to do.
   $q->enqueue($_) for 1..14;

   # When you're done adding, wait for the workers to finish.
   $q->end();
   $_->join() for threads->list;
}
```

Comment: where should I call my subroutine for my thread ? Do I need to place my subroutine call in print("Job: $job\n");

Comment: I've faced serious issue in this code. If one thread stops, automatically other threads are stopped.

Comment: Re "Same error occured what i 've received for old code. Free to wrong pool 1faa7a8 not 3f4c20 at line 114", My code doe snot have 114 lines, so I don't know why you tell me that.

Comment: Re "If one thread stops, automatically other threads are stopped." No idea what that means. "Stopping" is not something a thread can do.

Comment: Re "where should I call my subroutine for my thread ?" `worker` is your subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

This code only does 4 threads, and then stops. It doesn't process the remaining 6 items in the queue.